# When I want to access SMS, the error "Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference" appears

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, sms

I tried to retrieve SMS and then added to the Firebase realtime database and change the balance of specific account but this error appears when I want to change the balance:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.nouraalqahtani.debrah2, PID: 4500
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
>                         at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
>                         at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
>                         at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:539)
>                         at com.example.nouraalqahtani.debrah2.accesssms$3.onDataChange(accesssms.java:304)
>                         at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:75)
>                         at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:63)
>                         at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:55)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

and this accesssms class

```
package com.example.nouraalqahtani.debrah2;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

  import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
  import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
  import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
  import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
  import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

   import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Date;
   import java.util.Locale;


public class accesssms extends AppCompatActivity {
private static accesssms inst;
ArrayList<String> smsMessagesList = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView smsListView;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
DatabaseReference myRef;
String day;
String updatebalance;
String accounting;
String accountnumber;
String smsbody;
int count;
int childrencount;
double balance;
double amount;
int  childrencountinflow;
String type;
String bank;
String amountstr;

public static accesssms instance() {
    return inst;
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    inst = this;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_accesssms);
    myRef= 
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user_account").child(" . 
   (username)").child("bank_accounts");
    day = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", 
    Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    smsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SMSList);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsMessagesList);
    smsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    // Add SMS Read Permision At Runtime
    // Todo : If Permission Is Not GRANTED
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(),"android.permission.READ_SMS") ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Todo : If Permission Granted Then Show SMS
        refreshSmsInbox();

    } else {
        // Todo : Then Set Permission
        final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(accesssms.this, new String[] 
        {"android.permission.READ_SMS"}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
          }

             }
public void refreshSmsInbox() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
    int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
    if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
    arrayAdapter.clear();
    do {
        String str = "SMS From: " + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) +
                "\n" + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
        arrayAdapter.add(str);


        //if it samba bank
        if (smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress).equals(".Samba")) {
            smsbody = smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody);

            int ende = smsbody.indexOf(' ');
            final String transaction = smsbody.substring(0, ende);
            //to check if it outflow or inflow

            //if it outflow
            if (transaction.equals("دفع")) {

                type = "outflow";


                myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                     @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                         //Take last three number card number
                         int accountnumberstart = smsbody.lastIndexOf(".");
                         count = accountnumberstart +5;
                         accountnumber = smsbody.substring(accountnumberstart+2 , count);

                         for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                             String dataaccountOUT = ds.child("account_no").getValue(String.class);

                             if (Integer.parseInt(accountnumber)==Integer.parseInt(dataaccountOUT)) {


                                 childrencount=(int)ds.child("outflow").getChildrenCount();
                                 bank=ds.getKey();
                                 addoutflow();

                             } } }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }}); }



            else if (transaction.equals("تم")) {
                type = "inflow";
                //take account number

                myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //Take the last four numbers of account number
                        int accountnumberstart = smsbody.indexOf("حساب");
                        count = accountnumberstart+15 ;
                        accountnumber = smsbody.substring(accountnumberstart +11, count);
                                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                              String dataaccount = ds.child("fourfirstdigit").getValue(String.class);
                              if (Integer.parseInt(accountnumber)==Integer.parseInt(dataaccount)){
                                childrencountinflow=(int)ds.child("inflow").getChildrenCount();
                                bank=ds.getKey();
                                addinflow();

                        }

                    }}


                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


            }
        }} while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());

    blanacechange();
   }





public void updateList(final String smsMessage) {
    arrayAdapter.insert(smsMessage, 0);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}




public void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}





public void addoutflow(){

   // counter=counter+1;
 //   String co=Integer.toString(counter);
        int accounttotalstart = smsbody.lastIndexOf("بقيمة");
        int accounttotalend = smsbody.lastIndexOf("ريال");
        accounting = smsbody.substring(accounttotalstart + 6, accounttotalend);

        amountstr=arabicToenglish(accounting);
        myRef.child(bank).child("outflow").child("6").child("amount").setValue(amountstr);

        //change the balance



        //take vendor name
        int vendorstart = smsbody.lastIndexOf("*", count + 1);
        int vendorend = smsbody.lastIndexOf(",");

        String vendor = smsbody.substring(vendorstart + 3, vendorend);
        //add vendor name to database
        myRef.child(bank).child("outflow").child("6").child("vendor").setValue(vendor);



        //add current time

        int timstart = smsbody.lastIndexOf(",");
        int timend = smsbody.lastIndexOf("/");
        String date = smsbody.substring(timstart + 1, timend + 4);
        myRef.child(bank).child("outflow").child("6").child("date").setValue(arabicToenglish(date));


        int ti = smsbody.lastIndexOf(" ");
        String time = smsbody.substring(timend + 4, ti);
      //  myRef.child(bank).child("outflow").child("6").child("time").setValue(arabicToenglish(time));
        //to check if it AM OR PM

        String AMorPM = smsbody.substring(ti + 1);

        if (AMorPM.equals("صباحاً")) {
            myRef.child(bank).child("outflow").child("6").child("time").setValue(arabicToenglish(time) + " AM");
        } else
            myRef.child(bank).child("outflow").child("6").child("time").setValue(arabicToenglish(time) + " PM");


    }





public void addinflow(){

        int accounttotalstart = smsbody.lastIndexOf("مبلغ");
        int accounttotalend = smsbody.indexOf(" ");
        accounting = smsbody.substring(accounttotalstart + 4, accounttotalend);
    amountstr=arabicToenglish(accounting);


    myRef.child(bank).child("inflow").child("2").child("amount") 
     .setValue(amountstr);

        //change the balance



        int timstart = smsbody.lastIndexOf("في");
        int timend = smsbody.lastIndexOf("-");
        String date = smsbody.substring(timstart + 2, timend + 5);
        myRef.child(bank).child("inflow").child("2").child("date").setValue(arabicToenglish(date));


        int ti = smsbody.lastIndexOf(" ");
        String time = smsbody.substring(timend + 4, ti);
        myRef.child(bank).child("inflow").child("2").child("time").setValue(arabicToenglish(time));
        //to check if it AM OR PM

        String AMorPM = smsbody.substring(ti + 1);
        if (AMorPM.equals("صباحاً")) {
            myRef.child(bank).child("inflow").child("2").child("time").setValue(time + " AM");
        } else
            myRef.child(bank).child("inflow").child("2").child("time").setValue(time + " PM");


}


private static String arabicToenglish(String number)
{
    char[] chars = new char[number.length()];
    for(int i=0;i<number.length();i++) {
        char ch = number.charAt(i);
        if (ch >= 0x0660 && ch <= 0x0669)
            ch -= 0x0660 - '0';
        else if (ch >= 0x06f0 && ch <= 0x06F9)
            ch -= 0x06f0 - '0';
        chars[i] = ch;
    }
    return new String(chars);
}


public void blanacechange() {


    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           String databa = dataSnapshot.child(bank).child("balance").getValue(String.class);
            String am = dataSnapshot.child(bank).child("6").child("amount").getValue(String.class);
           balance=Double.parseDouble(databa);
           amount=Double.parseDouble(am);



            if (type.equals("outflow")){
                balance = balance - amount;
            myRef.child(bank).child("balance").setValue(Double.toString(balance));}

            if (type.equals("inflow")){
                balance=balance+amount;
                myRef.child(bank).child("balance").setValue(Double.toString(balance));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}



  }
```

And this my database

[image]

Comment: I cannot see in your code where you are using `trim()` method? Can you please also share that part of code?

Comment: Create [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), don't paste ~300 lines of code

Comment: I wrote some hints on how to troubleshoot the problem below. But *please* read the link to [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that barbsan also provided, as it is incredibly hard to help with the amount of code you shared.

Comment: I didn't use the trim()

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you have:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference

Which means that somewhere in your app, some code is calling `trim()` on a `null`. Since your code doesn't contain any calls to `trim`, you need to follow along on your stack trace to see what call in your code actually causes the problem.

And it tells you that this happens:

> at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
>
> at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
>
> at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:539)
>
> at com.example.nouraalqahtani.debrah2.accesssms$3.onDataChange(accesssms.java:304)

Now that last line is the first one that you can recognize. The problem occurs on line 304 of `accesssms.java`. You can check what exact line that is in your IDE, but I went off the fact that apparently you call `parseDouble` on that line. So the problem is starts at a call to `parseDouble`.

If I look at the code you shared, you call `parseDouble` on these two rows:

```
      String databa = dataSnapshot.child(bank).child("balance").getValue(String.class);
        String am = dataSnapshot.child(bank).child("6").child("amount").getValue(String.class);
       balance=Double.parseDouble(databa);
       amount=Double.parseDouble(am);
```

So the problem must come from either of these rows. In either case it seems likely that you're getting `null` back from the call to `getValue(String.class)`, meaning that there either isn't a value in the snapshot, or (less likely) that the value isn't a string.

It's hard to follow precise what you're data you're listening, but as far as I can see you initialize `myRef` as:

```
myRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user_account").child(" . 
(username)").child("bank_accounts");
```

If that is the case, please first check that the `.` in there is not causing the problem.

If it indeed isn't, you have a reference here to all bank accounts of a user. So if you attach a `ValueEventListener` to that reference, your `onDataChange` get called with a `DataSnapshot` all of bank accounts. To get to each individual bank account you'll need to loop over the child nodes of that snapshot. Something like:

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       for (DataSnapshot accountSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
           String databa = accountSnapshot.child("balance").getValue(String.class);
            String am = accountSnapshot.child("amount").getValue(String.class);
            balance=Double.parseDouble(databa);
            amount=Double.parseDouble(am);
           ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```